# How save images from Whatsapi to aws s3

Tags: amazon-s3, whatsapp

I want to save media/pictures message from https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI to AWS S3. I tried this code, it can get the images and no errors on local but it's not save to AWS S3.

```
require_once 'S3.php';
require_once 'src/whatsprot.class.php';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$nickname = 'nickname';
$bucket = 'mybucket';
$accesskey = 'accesskey';
$secretkey = 'secretkey';

$fileName = $_FILES['pictures/']['name'];
$fileTempName = $_FILES['pictures/']['tmp_name'];
$options = array('params' => array('ACL' => 'public-read', 'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'));

$s3 = new S3($accesskey, $secretkey);

function onGetImage($mynumber, $from, $id, $type, $t, $name, $size, $url, $file, $mimetype, $filehash, $width, $height, $preview){
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$fulluri = "pictures/" . $file;
$fp = @fopen($fulluri, "w");
if ($fp) {
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}
S3::putObject(S3::inputFile($file), $bucket, $uri, $options);
}

$w = new WhatsProt($username, 0, $nickname, true);
$w->eventManager()->bind("onGetImage", "onGetImage");
$w->connect();
$w->loginWithPassword($password);
$w->pollMessage($autoReceipt = true);
$messages = $w->getMessages();
```

Please guide me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: so, what's wrong here? what are you asking for? do you have any errors? if yes, please show it to use

Comment: No error at local.
I edited my question.